# How do we run a court case?

Tags: unknown-armies, unknown-armies-3e

So I just got into unknown armies 3rd addition and decided to run a game with a few friends. Now the beginning of the session they decided to get one on the NPCs into the group and I rolled with it. So they call her up and invite her to a road trip out in the desert for a few days. She declined because of her job (she's a manager at Starbucks) so the party decided the best way to get the NPC to go was to  break into the mall and burn the Starbucks she works at down to the ground but they got caught.

So are there any rules for running a court case?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the tour. While the site can totally scour rulebooks for you so as to point you in the right direction, what if there aren't any rules for this? Is *No* a satisfactory answer, or would you find experiences from those who've run trials in *Unknown Armies* worthwhile? Thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: I've added a new tag for 3rd edition Unknown Armies because my understanding is that the new edition has a few departures from the rules of previous editions. Feel free to delete it if you disagree with this

Answer (score 2):

Unknown Armies Book 1: Play suggests using the Gridiron extended contest rules for trials, with a brief description on page 70 of the suggested skills (Connect, Status, Lie, Notice) and the potential outcomes (ranging from "Guilty as Hell" to "Exonerated").